# Analogue of C# HMACSHA1.ComputeHash in C ++?

Tags: c#, c++, hmacsha1

C# code:

```
HMACSHA1 hmacGenerator = new HMACSHA1();
hmacGenerator.Key = sharedSecretArray;
byte[] hashedData = hmacGenerator.ComputeHash(timeArray);
```

Variable types:

```
byte[] sharedSecretArray
byte[8] timeArray
```

How can i get the same hash data in C++?

Comment: There are no `SHA1` generators built into c++. You need to make your own or use an existing library.

Comment: Native C++ or C++ .NET? The .NET variant just can use any .NET Library like any other .NET Language.  For C++, you have to hunt for native code or precompiled libraries.

Comment: You could look at this: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Hmac-Computation-Sample-11fe8ec1/sourcecode?fileId=42820&pathId=283874677.  It uses "CNG" (the Cryptography Next Generation) Windows libraries.  They are FIPS certified.